# Calculated SQL column in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    a.OtherMeasurementID
    , a.MeasurementID
    , b.MeasurementCode
    , a.OperationDate
    , a.OperationTime
    , a.AccumulatedMass 
    , CAST(a.OperationDate AS datetime) + CAST(a.OperationTime as datetime) oDateTime
INTO 
    #_OtherMeasurement
FROM 
    _OtherMeasurement a 
INNER JOIN 
    _Measurement b ON a.MeasurementID = b.MeasurementID
WHERE 
    a.OperationDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @StartDate) 
    AND a.OperationDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
    AND b.MeasurementCode LIKE '%Inlet%'

--============================================
;with CTE as
(
    select 
        T1.OtherMeasurementID
        , t1.MeasurementID
        , T1.MeasurementCode
        , T1.OperationDate
        , T1.OperationTime
        , T1.AccumulatedMass
        , case when T1.AccumulatedMass = 0 then 0 else T1.AccumulatedMass - T2.AccumulatedMass end as ReceivedMass
        , T1.oDateTime
    From 
        #_OtherMeasurement T1
    left join
        #_OtherMeasurement T2 on T1.MeasurementCode = T2.MeasurementCode 
                    and DATEADD(Hour, -1, T1.oDateTime) = T2.oDateTime
    left join 
        #_OtherMeasurement T3 on T1.MeasurementCode = T3.MeasurementCode 
                    and DATEADD(Hour, 1, T1.oDateTime)= T3.oDateTime
)
,CTE2 as
(      
    select 
        T1.OtherMeasurementID
        , T1.MeasurementID
        , T1.MeasurementCode
        , T1.OperationDate
        , T1.OperationTime
        , T1.AccumulatedMass             
        , case when T1.AccumulatedMass = 0 then (T2.ReceivedMass + T3.ReceivedMass)/2 else T1.ReceivedMass end as ReceivedMass        
    From 
        CTE T1
    left join 
        CTE T2 on T1.OperationDate = T2.OperationDate and T1.MeasurementCode = T2.MeasurementCode 
                and DATEADD(Hour, -1, T1.oDateTime)= T2.oDateTime
    left join 
        CTE T3 on T1.OperationDate = T3.OperationDate and T1.MeasurementCode = T3.MeasurementCode 
                and DATEADD(Hour, 1, T1.oDateTime)= T3.oDateTime 
)
select 
    OtherMeasurementID,
    MeasurementID,
    MeasurementCode,
    OperationDate,
    OperationTime,
    AccumulatedMass,
    coalesce(ReceivedMass, 0) ReceivedMass
from 
    CTE2
WHERE
    OperationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

if you see on the CTE2, there's a line

```
case when T1.AccumulatedMass = 0 then (T2.ReceivedMass + T3.ReceivedMass)/2 else T1.ReceivedMass end as ReceivedMass
```

That line will work if zero value on accumulated mass on the same date. The data for the table is hourly base. If the zero value is on 10/Jan/2015 23:00:00 , then the line won't work. because the next value should be on 11/Jan/2015 00:00:00. sample statement is, if value before and after zero is on the same date, the calculation will work. If not, then won't work.

My question is, how can I make the formula work even the next value after zero is on different date..?

Example:

```
OtherMeasurementID  MeasurementID   MeasurementCode OperationDate   OperationTime   AccumulatedMass ReceivedMass
17                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  17:00:00           236265.36    518.58
18                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  18:00:00           236795.95    530.59
19                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  19:00:00           0            533.57
20                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  20:00:00           237865.13    536.55
21                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  21:00:00           238404.14    539.01
22                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  22:00:00           238944.05    539.91
23                       1         Water Inlet         13-Oct-2014  23:00:00           0            0
24                       1         Water Inlet         14-Oct-2014  0:00:00            240026       240026
25                       1         Water Inlet         14-Oct-2014  1:00:00            240566.98    540.98
26                       1         Water Inlet         14-Oct-2014  2:00:00            241107.92    540.94
```

If you can see on the example above. at 13/Oct/2015 19:00, the accumulatedmass is zero. so the formula to calculate the receivedmass is `(previous receivedmass before zero + next receivedmass after zero) / 2`

But, if you see on 13/Oct/2015 23:00, the formula above doesn't work,, because the `next receivedmass after zero` is on another date which is 14/Oct/2015 00:00.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try to simplify your query down to just something that deals with the problem at hand (i.e. I'd expect `CTE` could for the time being be replaced with a table variable) with some sample data and expected results. At the moment, there's a lot of query to expect us to understand and we a) don't have access to your database and b) don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You are joining on `T1.OperationDate = T3.OperationDate`, thus you limit it to the same day. What would happen if you remove this part from the `join`? (and remove `T1.OperationDate = T2.OperationDate` as well - same problem if `accumulatedmass` was zero at `00:00`)

Comment: Do you store `date` in one column and `time` in another column? Rather than storing `datetime` in one column? Well... Combine them into proper `datetime` before adding and subtracting 1 hour from it in the joins. Ah. You **are** doing it already. So, just remove comparison of dates from the join.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, can't be remove it. The calculation didn't work at all. 'cause it has to get the previous and after value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change from:

```
left join CTE T3 on T1.OperationDate = T3.OperationDate and T1.MeasurementCode = T3.MeasurementCode and DATEADD(Hour, 1, T1.oDateTime)= T3.oDateTime
```

to:

```
left join CTE T3 on (T1.OperationDate = T3.OperationDate and T1.MeasurementCode = T3.MeasurementCode and DATEADD(Hour, 1, T1.oDateTime)= T3.oDateTime) or (dateadd(day, 1, T1.OperationDate) = T3.OperationDate and T1.MeasurementCode = T3.MeasurementCode and DATEADD(Hour, 1, T1.oDateTime)= T3.oDateTime)
```